# how to prevent react-router-dom nested routes to get confused with route params

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two different routes which are supposed to return two different components:

a route for showing a form to create a new post:

```
<Route exact path='/posts/new'
   render={(props) => <NewPost
       {...props}
   />}/>
```

and another route to show a post by id:

```
<Route exact path='/posts/:id'
   render={(props) => <ShowPost
       {...props}
   />}/>
```

the problem is that when I try to reach the /posts/new, I will hit the ShowPost with a param of "new".

ps. I have to keep the route's naming convention as it is, because I'm mocking a non SPA website, and the links should be the same for SEO's sake.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think declaring the `posts/new` route above the `posts/:id` should fix the problem.

Comment: I already did that trick but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your routes in the Switch component making sure /posts/new is above the other one.
(Switch renders the first child that matches the location).

```
import {Switch} from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
<Route exact path='/posts/new'
                       render={(props) => <NewPost
                           {...props}
                       />}/>
 <Route exact path='/posts/:id'
                       render={(props) => <ShowPost
                           {...props}
                       />}/>
</Switch>
```